# How to count number of lines and perform operations in functional way in D?

Tags: file, functional-programming, d

I have the following piece of code:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.array;
import std.csv;
import std.stdio;
import std.typecons;
import std.getopt;
import std.file;
import std.conv;

struct DataPoint{
    double x,y,z;

    this(double _x, double _y, double _z){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }

    this(char[][] a){
        x = to!double(a[0]);
        y = to!double(a[1]);
        z = to!double(a[2]);
    }

    DataPoint opBinary(string s)(DataPoint d) if (s == "+"){
        auto ret = DataPoint(x + d.x, y + d.y, z + d.z);
        return ret;
    }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    string csvFile;
    try{
        getopt(args, std.getopt.config.required, "input|i", &csvFile);
        assert(csvFile.isFile);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        writeln(e.msg);
        return;
    }

    auto file = File(csvFile, "r");
    int lineCount = 0;
    foreach (string line; lines(file)){
        ++lineCount;
    }
    file.close();

    file = File(csvFile, "r");
    auto aa = file.byLine()                      // Read lines
                       .map!split                // Split into words
                       .map!(a => DataPoint(a))
                       .reduce!((a,b) => a + b);
    auto average = DataPoint(aa.x/lineCount, aa.y/lineCount, aa.z/lineCount);

    std.stdio.writefln("After reading %d records, "
                      ~"the average is [%.2f, %.2f, %.2f]", lineCount, average.x, average.y, average.z);
}
```

How can I count the number of lines in the file while iterating over its contents at the same? (in one pass)

Comment: A simple foreach on each line while incrementing a variable is probably the easiest way. Looking at your code you almost having. Use your algorithm function inside of the foreach loop and you should be good to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very functional, but you can use `tee` for inline processing:

```
int count = 0;
auto x = stdin.byLine.tee!(_ => ++count).map!(/+ ... whatever ... +/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map an identity increment function before splitting into words, like so:

```
file.byLine()
    .map!((a){ lineCount++; return a; })
    ...
```

Also, you should look into using `fold` instead of `reduce`, due to weird parameter ordering of the latter when using a start value.